# Transform appsettings.json in Release pipeline with another appsettings file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In my .NET Core project I have a `appsettings.json` file and a `appsettings.Test.json` file.

I have a release pipeline where I would like to override the settings in `appsettings.json` with those in `appsettings.Test.json`.

Is this possible?

I tried to do the following in my "IIS Web App Deploy" task:

[image]

But the content of `appsettings.Test.json` isn't transformed into `appsettings.json`.

It does however work for the variables that I define in the "Variables" tab. But that's not what I'm after.

[image]

Is there a way to tell the release pipeline to tranform the `appsettings.json` file with another file like `apssettings.Test.json` in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You must use Transfrom File:

```
stages:
- stage: TransformFiles
  displayName: TransformFiles
  jobs:
    - job: Transform_AppSettings
      steps:      
      - bash: echo "===== Transforming appsettings.json for $(variables['Build.SourceBranchName']) environment ====="
      - task: FileTransform@2
        inputs:
          folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
          fileType: 'json'
          targetFiles: 'appsettings.json'
```

You can use variables or variable groups. Here is an example of how you can replace the Connection string. I have variable group prod-secrets with key psql-conn-conn-str-prod.

```
- group: prod-secrets
- name: ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection
  value: $(psql-conn-str-prod)
```